# Subset pandas timeseries dataframe from looping if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, spyder

Please let me know if the title of my problem is accurate - I think I need a looping if statement to solve the problem below - I am a newbie to Python and programming in general, so don't know if the terminology is correct.

I am using Spyder, working on a research project.

I need to create a new variable in the existing data frame (df) which provides the following logic:

- > Between time T1 (1st occurrence of the number 1 in column e1) and time T2 (2nd 1 in e1), if there is a 1 recorded between T1 and T2 for any of the variables (e2 or e3) *or* the value of v1 between T1 and T2 is greater than 1, then place a 1 in a new column called 'result' between T1 and T2.
- > Between time T2 (2nd occurrence of the number 1 in column e1) and time T3 (3rd 1 in e1), if there is a 1 recorded between T2 and T3 for any of the variables (e2 or e3) *or* the value of v1 between T2 and T3 is greater than 1, then place a 1 in a new column called 'result' between T2 and T3.

Between T3 and T4 etc. etc.

Following the above, I will create a subset of the data based on all rows that have a 1 in 'result' for further analysis.

To recreate a small part of df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


df = pd.DataFrame({'e1' : [1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan],
                    'e2' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                    'e3' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                    'v1' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.2,1.5,1,1],},
                        index=pd.date_range('2019-05-02T00:00:00', '2019-05-02T01:00:00', freq='5T'))
```

The result should be:

```
'result' : [1,1,1,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,np.nan,np.nan]
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you!

**Edit 31.05.2019**

The solution suggested works for most instances, however, fails in a critical way:

I have edited the sample data to include an instance where there is an observation in both e1 and e2 at 00:25:00.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'e1' : [1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan],
                    'e2' : [np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                    'e3' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]},
                        index=pd.date_range('2019-05-02T00:00:00', '2019-05-02T01:00:00', freq='5T'))
```

**The issue**

The problem I have is that the suggested solution is reporting a result between 00:25:00 and 00:40:00, where I want the result to not include this. I want the code to analyze the times between the 1's in column e1, not including the time of the observation's in e1.

I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by masking and groupby:

```
# if there is an event at that time
events = df[['e2','e3']].notna().any(axis=1)

# if v1 > 1 at given time
v1g1 = df['v1'].gt(1)

# mask
mask = v1g1 | events

# group the events by e1 
df['result'] = mask.groupby(df.e1.fillna(0).cumsum()).transform('any')

# if you want 1 and NaN:
df['result'] = np.where(mask.groupby(df.e1.fillna(0).cumsum()).transform('any'),
                        1, np.nan)
```

Output is `True`, `False` other than `1, NaN`:

```
                        e1      e2      e3      v1      result
2019-05-02 00:00:00     1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     True
2019-05-02 00:05:00     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0     True
2019-05-02 00:10:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     True
2019-05-02 00:15:00     1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     True
2019-05-02 00:20:00     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0     True
2019-05-02 00:25:00     1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     False
2019-05-02 00:30:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     False
2019-05-02 00:35:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     False
2019-05-02 00:40:00     1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     True
2019-05-02 00:45:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.2     True
2019-05-02 00:50:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.5     True
2019-05-02 00:55:00     1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     False
2019-05-02 01:00:00     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     False
```

Comment: Hi, this is not working. I have an issue, where in my data if I have an observation (in e2 or e3) at the same time as the event in e1, it includes this in the final result. I need the code to work in the times in between T1 and T2, not including T1 and T2. I have added an edit to my original question. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited the original question with an updated example of my data, to demonstrate the issue I am experiencing. The issue is that the solution includes T1 and T2, but I need the solution to not include T1 and T2, but to work with the time between T1 and T2.

Comment: Apologies, my results column appear incorrect. I will edit.